# Cropping an UIImage. Cropped Image is Not Correct

Tags: ios

I have a UIImageView on the screen. It displays an image with several colors. When I click on the image it crops a small portion of the image and set the cropped image to a new small UIImageView. For some reason the cropped image is always wrong. Check out the screenshot below:

[image]

Here is the complete code for touchesBegin:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.imageView];

    UIImage *originalImage = self.imageView.image;

    NSLog(@"x = %f, y = %f",location.x,location.y);

    CGRect cropRegion = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 10, 10);

    CGImageRef subImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(originalImage.CGImage, cropRegion);

    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:subImage scale:originalImage.scale orientation:originalImage.imageOrientation];

    [self.previewImageView setImage:croppedImage];

    CGImageRelease(subImage);

}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but if you compare the size of the raw image and the size of the UIImageView you'll probably see that the point of 'location' is most likely not in the spot where you are touching, compared to the coordinates on the raw image. The image is probably being scaled to fit in the UIImageView, so you'll need to adjust the coordinates to give you the correct location.

Comment: @BrianShamblen, so how do u do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the image size is larger than the view size, and so the image has been shrunk to fit the view.  The result is that the view coordinates do not match the image coordinates, and hence the point returned by `locationInView` cannot be used directly for the `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`.

To solve this problem you need to determine the x and y scale factors based on the `self.imageView.bounds.size` and the `originalImage.size`, and then scale the `location` accordingly.

Comment: Bingo! You are 100% correct sir :) I was scratching my brain for almost an hour :)